# Connect to VisualSVN from a network compter?

Tags: svn, windows-7, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I have the following situation:
New laptop with Windows 7 professional and IIS installed.
The laptop is wireless connected to a home network that has workstation with xp sp 3.

I have installed VisualSVN Server 2.1.4 and imported a repository from the workstation and checked it out on the laptop.

Now I want to be able to relocate the checked out version on the workstation to point to the new repository on the laptop.

I'm using TurtoiseSVN on both the laptop and workstation.
When trying to relocate the repository, in the relocate dialog for URL I enter the VisualSVN Server from the laptop which is: `https://lap1/svn`

But I get an error message saying that it could not connect to the server. 
I can't connect to the server using FF either so I think it's a setup issue but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely name resolution or routing is not correctly configured in your LAN. It's unlikely that this has something to do with SVN, it's a general network problem.

Post more details about your server config and setup, then maybe we can help.

BTW, this belongs on superuser.com, as it's not about a programming problem. It will move there automatically once four more users have voted for it.

*Edit:*

If you can connect via IP address, but not by name, your name resolution is not working. How to fix this depends on your network setup.

Comment: Once it has been moved to superuser.com can I post more info about it?

Comment: @Mike: Yes, you can always edit your question. If it moves to superuser.com, you need to associate your accounts on superuser and stackoverflow.

Comment: just a quick update. I can connect using the laptop IP address but not by name.

Comment: @Mike: Please post updates to your question by editing the question - not everyone reads the comments.